# Find maximum using foreach in Scala

Tags: scala, foreach

I have some collection, that implements `def foreach(f: MyType => Unit): Unit`.

`MyType` has member `val value: Int` that is greater or equals to zero in normal case.

How coud i find element with maximum `value` using `foreach`?

***UPD:***

There should be method `def max: MyType` within `MyType` implementing this logic.

Comment: Any reason not to use an implicit custom implementation of Ord and Collection.max?

Comment: Is your collection implements any trait from `scala.collection`?

Comment: @senia Maybe [Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable) conforms to given definition of `foreach`?

Comment: @Errandir: no, it should be `def foreach[U](f: MyType => U): Unit`. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to get this out of the way: I feel that `foreach` is not the right method for this particular problem. Since it doesn't have a return value, the only way for it to yield a result is by side effects / mutability, which is generally seen as something to avoid in Scala. You should probably look into the `reduce` and `fold` methods, or their specialised `min`, `max`... versions.

If you're really intent on using `foreach`, you need to pass a closure to `foreach` that updates a free `max` variable maintained outside of its scope.

This is off the cuff but should work:

```
def max: MyType = {
    var max = MyType(0)
    foreach {t =>
        if(t.value > max) max = t.value
    }
    max
}
```

Comment: `var max` is `Int` and you are trying to return it as `MyType`. Also note that there are negative integers.

Comment: You're entirely right about my type error, I'll edit the post. On the other hand, the question states that `MyType.val` is greater than or equal to 0, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

### Traversable

You could implement `scala.collection.Traversable` - then you could use method `maxBy` (and all other methods of `Traversable`):

```
import scala.collection.Traversable

case class MyType(value: Int)
class MyCollection {
  def foreach(f: MyType => Unit): Unit = Seq(MyType(3), MyType(5), MyType(2)) foreach f
}

implicit class MyCollectionTraversable(c: MyCollection) extends Traversable[MyType] {
  override def foreach[U](f: MyType => U): Unit = c.foreach{e => f(e); ()}
}
```

Usage:

```
new MyCollection().maxBy{_.value}
// MyType = MyType(5)
```

You could also add implicit `Ordering[MyType]` like this:

```
import scala.math.Ordering
implicit val myTypeOrd = Ordering.by{ (_: MyType).value }

new MyCollection().max
// MyType = MyType(5)
```

### Custom method

You could also add your custom method `max` manually but even in this case `MyCollectionTraversable` will be useful:

```
class MyCollectionTraversable(c: MyCollection) extends Traversable[MyType] {
  override def foreach[U](f: MyType => U): Unit = c.foreach{e => f(e); ()}
}

implicit class MyCollectionHelper(val c: MyCollection) extends AnyVal {
  def max: MyType = new MyCollectionTraversable(c).maxBy{_.value}
}
```

Usage:

```
new MyCollection().max
// MyType = MyType(5)
```